# How to setup a virtual subnet?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, lan, subnet, network-camera

Ubuntu 20.04 is installed on my machine. A network cable connect it to a network camera. I've installed three virtual machines via VirtualBox on it, one Windows XP and two Ubuntu 12.04.
What I need is that I setup a virtual network in which the camera, my machine and the three virtual machines be on the same subnet and may see each others as they might if they would be on a real LAN.
Is it possible? and if so, how?
Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116599/discussion-on-question-by-hamidi-how-to-setup-a-virtual-subnet).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's easy. Since you've no DHCP server, you need to set IP's manually. You should use Bridge networking. Don't forget to set netmask as well as the IP for the machines.